# Parse.com push notifications issue. unsubscribe not working, still receiving push notifications.(Android)

Tags: android, notifications, parse-platform

I have made an app which uses Parse.com push notifications. I have a settings page in which you can enable/disable push notifications. The settings page works well, it changes the preference used, but the push notifications won't stop.

Here is my code in which I subscribe/unsubscribe:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            pushNotificationsPreference = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("PUSH_NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCE", true);

            if (pushNotificationsPreference) {
                ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("Android", new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                        } else {
                            Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to subscribe for push" + e);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground("Android", new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Log.d("com.parse.push", "successfully subscribed to the broadcast channel.");
                        } else {
                            Log.e("com.parse.push", "failed to unsubscribe for push" + e);
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
```

If "pushNotificationsPreference" is false, it calls method "ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground("Android", new SaveCallback()", but it won't subscribe, i am still receiving them.

I went on Parse.com, and i'm only registered at "Android" channel.

Am i missing anything?

Comment: Does it unsubscribe successfully (in the log)? Also pointing out, you have your IF condition set up in reverse. IF (e == null) that means that there is no error, you have it the other way around. ALSO your preference most probably doesn't exist and it defaults to the value "true".

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
if (e == null) {
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
}
```

into `done()` of `ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground(...)`