# Parse.com android - disable push notifications

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I've started using parse.com to receive push notifications in my application.

It works perfectly, but I have a couple of questions.

We perform registration, but unused channels, as follows:

```
  ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.d("dmode", "Oks!");
                } else {
                    Log.e("dmode", "Fail :(", e);
                }
            }
        });
```

My first question is:

I find no way to disable receiving push notifications
I searched the official documentation and stackoverflow, but I find solutions that do not work for me.
I tried:

```
ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("dmode", "unsuscribe oks");
        } else {
            Log.e("dmode", "unsuscribe fail", e);
        }
    }
});
```

Unsuccessfully, I have also tried:

```
ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground("");
```

...but not work.

I'm not using channels, that is why the quotes are empty:

```
ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("", new SaveCallback() { //...
```

How I can enable and disable push notifications?

The second query is that sometimes receive duplicate notifications until two three times at once on the same device.
Someone has been the same?

Thank you very much for the help.

Greetings!

Comment: What do you mean that it does not work? Does the save callback return exception or does it not return at all?

Comment: Check this my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31091355/2311651 for the same question, pls.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a name for a default channel even if you are not using channels and not the empty string "".
Also have a look here [Parse Question](https://parse.com/questions/disable-push-notification-service)

I quote from the answer on the above link

> If you called PushService.setDefaultCallback, call it again passing null as the class.

Comment: I am having the same problem and I've also seen that [answer](https://parse.com/questions/disable-push-notification-service), but actually that method doesn't exist in the [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/PushService.html), and the only method that seem to be called quite alike is [`setDefaultPushCallback`](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/PushService.html#setDefaultPushCallback(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class)) but it's deprecated... So what should we do now ?

Comment: if it is deprecated or non-existent it means that you did not call it on the first time, right? Then just ignore this step. Just use the ParsePush.unsubscribeInBackground("channelname"); and you should be fine

Comment: Yeah but problem is that I am not using channels cause I am only making broadcast push notification ( always server to device )... If I have implemented a receiver class extending `ParsePushBroadcastReceiver` what method should I override to avoid showing notification in an android device ?